# How to register ApplicationContextInitializer in Spring boot 2.7/3

Tags: spring-boot

I'm using Spring boot 2.7.7 and Spring boot 3.

I've already switched to the new way write my custom autoconfiguration class - that is with @AutoConfiguration and org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfiguration.imports inside META-INF/spring folder.

I want to add ApplicationContextInitializer. How do I do it the last spring boot versions (2.7.7 and 3)? I tried to add it to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfiguration.imports file but initialize method is not being called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still use the spring.factories file